# Keyboard shortcut to start Calculator in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, calculator

Does anyone know it? Is there a way to create it?

Comment: Just noting that some keyboards have a calculator button (usually above the numbers-pad).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Find the shortcut to calculator in the Start menu, right click and select "Properties".  You can enter any shortcut you want in the "Shortcut Key" field.

Comment: This is the solution.  I like Ctrl-Alt-C, personally.

Comment: This doesn't work quite the same way, at least in Windows 8.1. If you have an actual Calculator button and press it 5 times then you will get 5 calculators open. If you create a shortcut key in Windows, pressing the shortcut 5 times will open it once and focus on it the next 4 times. You also can't open the calendar more than once by clicking on the shortcut in the start menu

Answer (score 16):

Well if you put it in your quicklaunch bar, the items there automatically get a shortcut (well the first 10 anyway) of **Windows + #**

Comment: Thanks, I know that, but I prefer to have a "clean" taskbar.

Answer (score 8):

Not a true shortcut key combination, but a comfortable way to do it anyway.
win-key+r [for the run window], type calc and press enter.

Might seems like a bit of work relatively for a shortcut, but if you're not completely rubbish at typing, it's easy and quick (and if you use the method for other programs you really get used to it).

Comment: I could do the same thing just pressing the Win key and typing calc.

Comment: Yes, but if you have other programs that contain with those letters and especially if you use them more, you might find yourself loading the wrong app.

Comment: hitting the win key and then typing "calc" won't let you open more than one, whereas using the run window will

Answer (score 6):

I know I sound like a fanboy, but I haven been using Microsoft keyboard for 9 years. I know it doesn't solve your problem in software, but all MS keyboard have a dedicate calculator button which I found very useful from time to time.

Comment: One of reasons I still keep this MS keyboard.