# How can I bind a keyboard shortcut to start a specific application in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, key-binding, application-launch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Keyboard shortcut to start Calculator in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/27463/keyboard-shortcut-to-start-calculator-in-windows-7)

I would like to bind a keyboard shortcut to the applications I use most so I can start them fast only using the keyboard.

Is this possible in Windows 7? How can I do it?

E.g. Bind <kbd>WinLogo</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> to start Eclipse. And bind <kbd>WinLogo</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> to start Spotify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure it under the program's "Properties".

[image: Screenshot]

Right-click on the program's icon (or Shift + Right-click on taskbar pinned items) and select "Properties".  Then, as highlighted above, you can configure the Shortcut key.  Hope that helps!